# Get all words in a PDF + their location without interop

Tags: c#, parsing, pdf, mono

I need to parse a PDF with C# code and get every word out of it plus the location of that word within the document. I cannot use interop as this will be running on Mono.

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: You should read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754996/how-to-parse-pdf-file-without-using-any-lib-or-software-in-c in other words what you want is not a simple request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try PDFBox. I believe there is an option to build the source into .NET dlls in the build script of the download package @ http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html. It utilizes IKVM, an implementation of the Java language for .NET Framework and Mono, to create a PDF library for the .NET framework.

You can use PDFBox to convert the PDF to text and get the x/y coordinates. An example has been done in Java @ https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/1.1.x/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintTextLocations.java. Perhaps it can be done in the .NET version.  However, I am not sure if the loss of formatting in parsing the pdf could produce  some inaccurate coordinates.